# Does google-chrome(browser) execute method calls which results are never used (for RuntimeTest)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, optimization, runtime

My Code looks like this:

```
var vorherGesammt=performance.now();
for(var k=0;k<anzahl_unterschiedlicherBrushesAufEinemTest;k++){
     dataIn=data.slice();
     intuitivBasic(dataIn,brushArray[k],idName);
}
naivZ=performance.now()-vorherGesammt;
console.log("laufzeitNaivGesammt",naivZ);
```

I want to test the runtime of the function intuitivBasic(). dataIn is modified during the function but then never used. So now i'm worried about if the function is really executed or if it is deleted during the code optimization and i only measure the time of the loop.
So the question is: **does chrome execute intuitivBasic() or not?**

Btw does chrome cash functioncalls with same parameters and reuse them or does chrome execute every single time?

thx in advanced
grettings Jones

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the results it seems so that chrome executes it